AdMob Implementation using Qt for iOS
Can someone please share some ideas/suggestions.
I am developing an app using Qt for iOS and I want to implement AdMob on iOS.
Unfortunately ,I can't implement AdMob.
We specify all the resources and files in CMakeLists.txt, But because Google Mobile Ads will be installed using Pod at later step and they will be included in .xcworkspace.
Because of this, there is an error saying Google Mobile Ads can not be found when I build .xcworkspace in Xcode.
We have two steps, one is in Qt Creator and other is in Xcode.

Should I download Google Mobile Ads manually in to Qt Directory, and tell CMake to find this , but I tried this and failed.
I tried on Xcode as well with no success.

